# Spoiler on table row with css selector

Tags: html, css, html-table, row

I'm trying to make a table that allows getting sub information when a row is clicked, I got the following code but I cannot make the sub information appears separately from each other

```css
#spoiler, #close {
    display: none;
}
#show:target #spoiler {
    display: table-row;
}
#show:target #open {
    display: none;
}
#show:target #close {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="show">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td> <a href="#show" id="open" class="trigger open">Company 1</a>
             <a href="#hide" id="close" class="trigger close">Company 1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td id="spoiler" class="spoiler">Company 1 Information</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <a href="#show" id="open" class="trigger open">Company 2</a>
             <a href="#hide" id="close" class="trigger close">Company 2</a>         </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
         <td id="spoiler" class="spoiler">Company 2 Information</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: ids can be used only once, that's why :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function toggle_visibility(id){
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'none')
            e.style.display = 'block';
        else
            e.style.display = 'none';
     }
     </script>   
</head>
<div id="show">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td> <a href="#" id="openOne" onclick="toggle_visibility('showOne');">Company 1</a>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td id="showOne" style="display:none">Company 1 Information</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <a href="#" id="openTwo" onclick="toggle_visibility('showTwo');">Company 2</a>
    </tr>
     <tr>
         <td id="showTwo" style="display:none">Company 2 Information</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</html>
```

Better and easier with using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You are using same id for more than one elements. You should seperate their id's from each other, this will fix your problem.

Comment: Could you give me a quick example? I'm really lost here

Comment: Is there any problem to use javascript?